# Medium (or general RSS) feed text-to-speech reader with voice control

Tags: android, osx, ios, rss, speech-synthesis

I'm looking for app, that can read aloud texts from RSS feed. Mac or iOS or Android.

- It should be able to distinguish languages of articles: I'm reading in English and sometimes in Russian
- It should show images on the screen while reading or just scrolling through the text while reading
- It should be able to respond to either voice commands, "stop", "play", "next", etc. Or at least respond to headphones buttons like pretty much all music applications do.

And there are few things that I don't expect to find, but it would be absolutely awesome:

- Quick way read teasers or just headers of articles till the moment when I'll command to read specific article.
- Do not read things that not suppose to be read: URLs, code snippets, etc.

This is pretty simple stuff to build. I can't believe no one has developed a good application for this. Currently, Pocket sort of does it, but the UX is awful and the voice is pretty bad.

Answer (score 1):

I developed [Intelligent Speaker](https://intelligent-speaker.com) for the related subset of problems. Now we do not support RSS natively but you can find some intermediate tools that will send your RSS messages to your inbound email in Intelligent Speaker service, where your texts (or links, with automatic language detection) will be synthesized to the podcast feed. Usually, every podcast app supports control through the headphones buttons. Inbound email today is not visible (service still in beta) - write to me if you need to get one.

Now if a user adds article through the browser extension - every podcast episode contains the link to the original article - and on some podcast apps you can preview this link right in the app or open in the default browser. I think that during RSS -> email -> podcast we will lose url to the original page - but it depends - maybe some popular intermediate RSS-to-email service will attach this link in some way too - so I can inject it to the podcast episodes.

Also, just curious - what search keyword did you try in your investigation? Maybe we need to add them to our website :)

Comment: awesome! Though, it looks like the submitted version is not stable, could you check it?

Comment: Submitted version usually works, but yes not stable. Did you catch some defect?